# Magento 2.0 Admin Not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I am using the virtual host on my local machine in WAMP.
Successfully installed the Magento 2.0.2 version. My URL is " magento2.com ".
magento2.com is working fine on localhost, but magento2.com/admin not working completely, it is only giving the error "Connection Reset".

I also tried with deleting all the cache from Magento directory, clear the browser cache and cookies but no success.

I have checked the log file and there is following message:

```
main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://magento2.com/admin","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

Please help to find some solution. It is annoying as it almost ruined my two days, but still no success.

Thanks & Regards
Rajnikant

Comment: Do you have `mod_rewrite` turned on? Anything in apache server logs?

Comment: You can test Maddy's suggestion by changing the URL to magento2.com/index.php/admin ... if that works, rewrites aren't enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if mod_rewrites are enabled. If they are disabled then please enable them. Also do check if the admin url is admin and not something else. For this you need to check app/etc/env.php

Thank you